# Can greats scientists and Mathematicians are considered as karma yogi?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

According to Gita  Can greats scientists and Mathematicians are considered as karma yogi ?

Thomas Edison , Ramanujan ,Einstein etc have done a great and revolutionary  contribution in science

Comment: karma yogi is anyone who does his duty ordained in scriptures without desire to experience its fruits. whether they did plain karma, or karma yoga - only they'll know.

Comment: Every human is doing work which is just karma. It has not relation to service of supreme lord Krishna. Scientists can't perform karma yoga because they don't believe in god . They are just karmis or karma bhogis.